# Scala manifest taken from variable and not instance?

Tags: scala, manifest

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question because I don't really understand what is going on.  But where I would expect a manifest to be able to tell me the actual runtime type of an instance, it seems to be telling me the runtime type of the variable it is assigned to.

```
// scala 2.10.1
trait Base
class Impl1 extends Base
class Impl2 extends Base

def showManifest[T <: Base](thing: T)(implicit ev: Manifest[T]) = println(thing + ": " + ev.runtimeClass)

val (impl1, impl2) = (new Impl1, new Impl2)

println("=== impl1 and impl2 ===")
showManifest(impl1)
showManifest(impl2)

val choose1 = if(true) impl1 else impl2
val choose2 = if(false) impl1 else impl2

println("=== choose1 and choose2 ===")
showManifest(choose1)
showManifest(choose2)
```

Output:

```
=== impl1 and impl2 ===
Main$$anon$1$Impl1@48ff2413: class Main$$anon$1$Impl1
Main$$anon$1$Impl2@669980d5: class Main$$anon$1$Impl2
=== choose1 and choose2 ===
Main$$anon$1$Impl1@48ff2413: interface Main$$anon$1$Base
Main$$anon$1$Impl2@669980d5: interface Main$$anon$1$Base
```

So, the type of choose1 and choose2 is Base, is that why the method ends up with Manifest[Base]?  Is there a way around this, so that I can pick a type I don't know at compile time (chosen by config parameter or the like) and pass it to a factory method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems all to be working as expected to me.  In all instances that you call `showManifest`, you are deferring to Type Inference to determine the type as opposed to passing in the type explicitly (i.e. `showManifest[Impl1](impl1)`).  So the type you see tied to the manifest will match the type of `val` you are passing in.  In the first two cases, type inference knows the exact concrete type and you see that reflected in what `showManifest` prints.  In the second two cases, because of the conditionals, type inference does not know exactly at compile time which one it will end up being and thus it moves up the type hierarchy for those two types until it finds a common type which ends up being `Base`.

I suppose if you wanted to try to get around this behavior, you could try something like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ManifestFactory
showManifest(choose1)(ManifestFactory.classType(choose1.getClass()))
```

Also, you should probably switch things over to `TypeTag`s/`ClassTag`s as `Manifest` has been deprecated in Scala 2.10

Comment: Yeah, I guess it isn't working as expected for me just because my expectations are off.  The manifest is pulled from the type of the var, there's no way to magically get it from the instance itself.  Good to know.  When I have a cnance I'll try the same example with TypeTag and see how that works.